# HTML Button Vertical Alignment

Tags: html, css

The following HTML generates buttons that are misaligned, the middle button is higher than the other two because of the wrapped text.  How can I get them aligned?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Status</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         .btn {
         background-color:red;
         font:bold 14px Arial;
         width:200;
         height:100;
         background-color:green;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <center>
      <br>
      <form>
         <button type=button class=btn onClick="#">Button 1<br>None</button>
         <button type=button class=btn onClick="#">Really Long Wrapped Button 2<br>None</button>
         <button type=button class=btn onClick="#">Button 3<br>None</button>
      </form>
   </center>
</html>
```

Comment: All 3 buttons seem to be aligned correctly for me in Chrome/Win7. What browser are you using? You're also missing quotes around your `button` attributes, not sure if that is a typo...

Comment: same display as @DrydenLong (Chrome) for Mozilla

Comment: IE 11 or FF 25.0.1 on Win7, both show them misaligned.   I also just tried Chrome 31 and it is misaligned there as well, but differently.  For IE and FF the middle button is shifted upward and for Chrome, the middle button is shifted downward.

Comment: Make sure you specify units in your class dimentions `width:200px;         height:100px;` to get consistent behavior

Comment: Hi Asraful, I realize I could increase the width of the button or decrease the font size to achieve the results I want.  However, I really would like to leave the font and button width fixed and have the button wrap work correctly.

Comment: Figured it out, I need the tag "vertical-align: middle;"  Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @user3108382 Can u please post the correct html/css as an answer so other can benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by the OP:

See the vertical-align tag below.

```
  <style type="text/css">
   .btn {
     background-color:red;
     font:bold 14px Arial;
     width:200;
     height:100;
     background-color:green;
     vertical-align: middle;
     }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I used to test this. It does seem to require "vertical-align: middle" for both IMG and BUTTON.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div {background-color: pink;}
            button {vertical-align: middle;}
            img {vertical-align: middle;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button>ABC</button>
            <button title=""><img src="anyimage.png">DEF</button>
            <button>GHI</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to increase width of the `class` btn to `width: 251px;` because inside the button you set 14px `font-size` which takes more than 240px ok and you have initialized 200px which cause align break.

after updating width the result is:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

for this you can use display: flex

```
form{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
form button{
  flex: 1;
}
```

[example here](https://jsfiddle.net/bjbrn1ca/2/)

[doc here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)